# Upload a drupal site to the server to test

Tags: migrations

I have finished the drupal website on my localhost. I want to upload everything to the server, but only to test before officially launching it. Is there a way that I can keep my current non-drupal website running normally, but also upload this drupal site and test it at the same time?

If I create a new directory on the root, say '/drupal_test, and put everything there for now, will that be a problem when I copy everything to the root later? Or is there any standard drupal way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I know, that should work.

Comment: Yes, that will work.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you instead use any other unused domain. In that case robots.txt, .httaccess will work normally. And also there is risk of Googlebot indexing this content.

Just add "Disallow:/" in the robots.txt as a first rule.

Comment: cool tip! I guess all it needs will be a host entry for the unused domin.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you end up putting the drupal site, so that you can point it!,putting the drupal codebase let say in a folder named as drupal_site inside your existing site root will help you accessing your drupal site with URL as www.existing.site/drupal_site.It will not harm your existing site.